# javascript disable event listener after first hit

Tags: javascript, events

How do I disable this event listener so that it only fires once?

```
document.getElementById('element').ontouchmove = function (e) 
{   
  DISABLE HERE
  do something that should only happen once
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('element').ontouchmove = function (e) {   
  this.ontouchmove = null;

  // Do something here.
};
```

Comment: Does setting the element to null prevent it from firing ever again?

Comment: @jamis0n, i'm simply replacing the function to be called once the even is fired with null.

Answer (score 0):

Set a Boolean to false after first execution, which will be checked each time before the function runs:

```
var doTouchEvent = true;
document.getElementById('element').ontouchmove = function (e) 
{   
   if(doTouchEvent){
      DISABLE HERE
      do something that should only happen once


      doTouchEvent = false;
   }
};
```